# Web Interface for embedded system

Tags: web-applications, frameworks, programming-languages, embedded, arm

I have an application which runs on an embedded system (400MHz, 64Mb of ram and 128Mb of free space on the sd card). I would like to build a Web Interface to communicate with the application. To do that I have to choose two things, the Web server and the Language to use (server-side). For now my searches lead me to these possibilities:

Web Server:

- lighttpd
- nginx

Both of these server support CGI and FastCGI.

The interface has to allow the users to authenticate and change language also. Users will have different access levels to the web interface, which means that some users will see the full web interface and others only some pages / options.

The server-side languages that I have found are these:

- PHP
- Python
- Lua
- C / C++

Are there others languages that I could use?

What kind of frameworks are available for these languages (keeping in mid that I don't have a lot of memory)?

I have already used WebPy (Python) and Kepler (Lua).

Comment: You can use any language that compiles for your platform?  It's not really clear from your question why one language or another wouldn't work for you.

Comment: Yes I can use any language, I would say that maybe PHP is a bit too heavy to be used in an embedded system...but maybe not, I'm not very familiar with embedded systems..

Comment: Bit disappointed at the closure, seems a reasonable question to me. I have a similar system, it's running Boa 0.94 server with some custom code to handle some basic functions. Boa supports .cgi scripting so you can use anything that will compile, although most of our stuff is hooked directly into Boa's source code as it's quite minimal and keeps things lightweight.

Comment: Yes I was too, thank you for your comment. I didn't mention Boa because (it seems to me that) it's no longer maintained and I'm looking for something that will last in time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar projects in which I have worked tend to use Python with either **[web.py](http://webpy.org/)** or **[bottlepy.org](http://bottlepy.org)**. They are simple to deploy and maintain and very light. If your project is simple, that is, you only need to build a minimal web, then I'd go for **web.py**, whereas if you need something more sophisticated **bottlepy** is better.

Comment: Thankyou, I will try bottlepy, but I'm worried by the fact that python is a bit heavy for an embedded system.

Comment: I have worked with embedded systems with similar specs as you have, and Python performed perfectly. BTW Remember upvote if you find it usefull ;)

Comment: Along the same lines is the Twisted Web modules: http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWeb